# How to filter the columns in ag-grid table using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

How to delete the columns in `ag-grid` table using column Id in `reactJs`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `setColumnVisible(colKey, visible)` in `columnApi`. It Sets the visibility of a column. `colKey` can be the column id or Column object. `visible` is a boolean, true to show, false to hide. I don't think you can remove a column, but you can hide or show it.

Refer documentation here - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api/

Comment: Sry sir.Wrongly posted.I want to filter the ag-grid table data using checkbox